# Google Image Search - is there an API that returns data in XML?

Tags: google-image-search

Is there a Google Image Search API that will return data in XML format?

I know about the AJAX API:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/

What I am looking for is a way to parse and display images from a Google Image Search query in my own UI.

I could try to parse the HTML results from a search like:

http://images.google.com/images?q=apple

But there is no guarantee that the HTML formatting will not change.

Is there an official non AJAX API for the same (like the book search API)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no API to get XML results for image search.

Comment: If Google gives you the search results as "plain data" (XML, JSON, etc), how can they make sure that you display their ads? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update (2016-11-18):**
The following API is no longer available.

> https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

You can indeed get results in JSON format, according to Google's AJAX Search API docs[1](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_fonje_urlbase).

For example, enter this URL in your browser to see JSON results for an image search for the query "water" on water.com:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=site:water.com+water
```

Note: you are limited to eight results at a time with this method. A list of optional query params is in the docs page I linked to.